# Laravel 5.4 Group By is not working due to isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

When I use my code it is working properly

```
 $pick_list_items = DB::table('pick_list_detail')
    ->select(['pick_list_detail.*','sale_invoice_detail.product_id','sale_invoice_detail.product_qty','sale_invoice_detail.uom','sale_invoice_detail.uom_factor'])
    ->where('pick_list_detail.pick_list_id',$id)
    ->join('sale_invoices','pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','sale_invoices.id')
    ->join('sale_invoice_detail','sale_invoice_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id')
    ->get();
```

I get the output I needed so it goes like this, there are many products in many sale_invoices and my query needs to group the product based on product_id so what I did was this :

```
 $pick_list_items = DB::table('pick_list_detail')
    ->select(['pick_list_detail.*','sale_invoice_detail.product_id','sale_invoice_detail.product_qty','sale_invoice_detail.uom','sale_invoice_detail.uom_factor'])
    ->where('pick_list_detail.pick_list_id',$id)
    ->join('sale_invoices','pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','sale_invoices.id')
    ->join('sale_invoice_detail','sale_invoice_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id')
    ->groupBy('sale_invoice_detail.product_id')
    ->get();
```

The error was this
[image: Error upon triggering]

Answer (score 0):

```
 $pick_list_items = DB::table('pick_list_detail')
    ->select(['pick_list_detail.*', 'sale_invoice_detail.product_id', 'sale_invoice_detail.product_qty', 'sale_invoice_detail.uom', 'sale_invoice_detail.uom_factor'])
    ->where('pick_list_detail.pick_list_id',$id)
    ->join('sale_invoices', 'pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','sale_invoices.id')
    ->join('sale_invoice_detail', 'sale_invoice_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id')
    ->groupBy('sale_invoice_detail.product_id')
    ->groupBy('pick_list_detail.id')
    ->get();
```

I have added another missing column in `group by` i.e `pick_list_detail.id`

Comment: If I am correct, now error column name is changed, you have to specify all non aggregated select column in group by, so add group by for error column and let me know

Comment: still not working mate, I tried to put all the aggregated column in groupBy, it works but it didnt group the productID

Comment: try to fix the query by doing `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` that will print the query run it in `mysql` and then convert it to Query Builder